# How to access i'th shape's attributes using d3

Tags: attributes, d3.js, geometry, shapes

I'm   building a simple geometry app using d3. The basic idea is you click three times and the app draws a circle through the three points you just clicked.

The d3 documentation mentions that that the d3 elements are stored as an array but doesn't make it clear how you access those elements. How can you access an element at a specific index in the selection?

Comment: Thanks for posting! I think the correct etiquette on StackOverflow is to break up the post into the question (your first 2 paragraphs) and your answer (the rest), which you post down below and then mark as the correct answer. This will properly close the question, so it won't show up as still needing an answer.

Comment: I tried to answer it but I don't have sufficient reputation points to do so.

Answer (score 0):

*Copied from the original question as a self-answer.*

This code snippet illustrates how to fetch the third circle's x position.

```
    var allCir= d3.selectAll("circle") ;
    var x =  d3.select(allCir[0][2]).attr("cx"); // get third circle's x position
    alert(x);
    d3.select(allCir[0][2]).attr("cx",10); // force it to an arbitrary value
```

Though the answer is simple, getting there wasn't so simple. Hope this helps.